# Node.js Firestore Error - Cannot encode value

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Discord.js to make a Discord bot, and I'm trying to use Cloud Firestore to keep a database of my values. I have the collection users in the firestore database. Here is what I have:

```js
//TOP OF CODE

let admin = require('firebase-admin');
let serviceAccount = require("./coinflipper-18c5c-firebase-adminsdk-cb16g-458fcb58c8.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

let firestore = admin.firestore();

//IN BOT.ON("MESSAGE") EVENT
//also by the way I use msg instead of message

let userData = firestore.doc(`users/${msg.author.id}`);
  if (!userData.exists) {
    console.log("creating...");
    userData.set({
        user: msg.author.id,
        badges: [],
        addons: {
          addonInv: [],
          buyNotification: false,
          customAddons: []
        },
        banned: false,
        cooldowns: {
          daily: 0,
          dropshipCooldown: false,
          exploreCooldown: false,
          flipCooldown: false,
          lotteryCooldown: false,
          monthly: 0,
          work: 0
        },
        currencies: {
          cents: 0,
          flipped: 0,
          minigames_won: 0,
          onto: 0,
          register: 0,
          timesWorked: 0
        },
        dropshipping: {
          list: [],
          priceList: [],
          helpMessageId: 0
        },
        inventory: [],
        job: "none",
        karate: {
          abilities: [],
          against: 0,
          askedBy: 0,
          askedTo: 0,
          belt: "NA",
          channel: 0,
          choosing: false,
          chosen_abilities: [],
          first: false,
          guild: 0,
          hp: 0,
          in_battle: false,
          level: 0,
          mhp: 0,
          mst: 0,
          name: "NA",
          st: 0,
          timesWon: 0,
          turn: false,
          type: "NA",
          xp: 0
        },
        lottery: {
          id: 0,
          prize: 0,
          won: false
        }
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

The console outputs `creating...` but then it outputs the error `Cannot encode value`
I tried with only the user field and it works, but adding any other field will cause it to do that same error. I also tried using two different `set` statements and making the first field a map with all the other fields, but neither of those worked.

[image: Full error message]

Comment: Which is these values is causing the error?

Comment: Badges - although any second value can be the error (for example if I erase badges, addons will be the problem)

Comment: And what is the complete error message, as usually it should tell you why it can't encode the value you pass in?

Comment: I have appended the error message to the question

Comment: The message you shared mentions "at Array.map", on firestore it's no possible to declare empty arrays. Try updating the set without the empty arrays and it should be able to encode the values

Comment: Thank you, I did it and it works

Comment: @SuperPhantomUser glad it worked, post it as a formal answer, please mark it as correct so other user can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you shared mentions "at Array.map", on firestore it's no possible to declare empty arrays. Update the set without the empty arrays and it should be able to encode the values.

This is similar to what is mentioned on this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462093/storing-empty-arrays-in-firebase) and I would recommend you take a look at [Firestore Best practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices)