# Firestore - cannot encode value - when adding a document using Promise.all() with MongoDB Insert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Initially I had this code:

```
const newUserObject = { name: "username", uid: "FirebaseUID", posts: [] }

await Promise.all([
    admin.firestore().collection("users").doc("FirebaseUID").set(newUserObject),
    mongoDb.collection("users").insertOne(newUserObject)
])
```

For some reason, this doesn't work and returns the error "cannot encode value". Here is the complete stack trace:

```
Cannot encode value: 60bb87e2cb98774f01d8bb0b
       at Serializer.encodeValue (~/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:168:15)
       at Serializer.encodeFields (~/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:57:30)
       at Function.fromObject (~/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/document.js:99:53)
       at Object.op (~/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:267:58)
       at ~/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:457:44
       at Array.map (<anonymous>)
       at WriteBatch._commit (~/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:457:31)
       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
       at async Promise.all (index 0)
   Caused by: Error
       at WriteBatch.commit (~/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:426:23)
       at DocumentReference.set (~/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:343:14)
       at ~/dist/handlers/users.js:75:68
       at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
       at fulfilled (~/dist/handlers/users.js:5:58)
       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

The value looks similar to MongoDB ObjectID but I am sure I am not passing that in Firestore object in any way. I checked an answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65801752/) which said you cannot set empty arrays in a new document but that doesn't seem right to me.

If I rewrite my code as follows, it works like charm.

```
await admin.firestore().collection("users").doc("FirebaseUID").set(newUserObject)
await mongoDb.collection("users").insertOne(newUserObject)
```

To confirm, nothing is undefined in the object I am trying to set. The issue occurs only when I use it with MongoDB's insertOne in a Promise.all().

**Steps to clone the issue:**

```
npm init -y
npm i firebase-admin mongodb
```

Then copy this code:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
const mongo = require("mongodb")

const client = mongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    auth: {
        user: "mongodbusername",
        password: "mongodbpassword"
    }
})

client.connect().then(async () => {
    console.log("MongoClient Connected");
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert("serviceAccountKey.json"),
        databaseURL: "https://<project-id>.firebaseio.com"
    })

    const newUserObject = {name: "NewUser", uid: "userUID", posts: ["PostID1"]}
    
    // UPDATING INDIVIDUALLY
    // await admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(newUserObject.uid).set(newUserObject)
    // await client.db("lasergg").collection("users").insertOne(newUserObject)
    // Works perfectly

    // UPDATING IN A PROMISE.ALL()
    await Promise.all([
        admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(newUserObject.uid).set(newUserObject),
        client.db("local").collection("users").insertOne(newUserObject)
    ])
    // Throws error Error: Cannot encode value: 60bdee0a77659f27d493dec8

    console.log("All Documents Added!");
})
```

I modified the source code of Firestore Node SDK [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/cd7e35c5e47f709399bd64d5620004ce9f494b0d/dev/src/serializer.ts#L211) and logged the 'val' parameter `[console.log(val, typeof val)]` that `encodeValue` function takes and the output was:

`60be04dd53e7965bf4a23173 object`

Edit: I logged values being passed in `encodeValue()` when running promises individually and the output is:

[image]

I ran the same when running in Promise.all():

[image]

This is what I edited in 'serialier.js':

[image]

Comment: Hello, quoting the thread you posted, I see that you're setting `posts` as an empty array. Have you tried with a non-empty one? The stack trace provided mentions Array.map as well, so that gives us a clue about the error

Comment: @DanielGomez I did try without an empty array. But I don't think empty arrays are issues as Firestore allows you to have empty arrays. That being said, the code works when I run both statements individually and not in a single `Promise.all()`

Comment: @DanielGomez I've added a MVP to clone the issue. You can try running it and try both the ways (promise all vs separate promies) and (with empty/non-empty array).

Comment: What's the issue with using separate promises if that works? What use case have you got that requires a single promise?

Comment: @afarre won't the promises run concurrently when using a promise.all() and throw an error even one of them fails?

Comment: Hey, I just noticed that the snippet for the promise has an extra `await` before the mongodb call. Could you try removing it ?

Comment: @DanielGomez sorry! That's a typo. Let me fix it.

Comment: @DanielGomez I retried without await (again that was a typo while editing here) but no luck :(
I'm wondering how the mongo doc ID is causing an issue for Firestore

Comment: Hello, I see that you logged the parameters passed to the function that fails to be `60be04dd53e7965bf4a23173 object`. Could you log the same information in the case of individual promises? If those parameters are different, that might give us a clue into what is failing.

Comment: @DanielGomez I've updated my question with required information! The complete code is already in question as well. I am still confused how the MongoDB document ID is being pushed into the 'encodeValue' function. The problem to me seems in the function `util_1.isPlainObject(val)` in serializer.js. That maybe due to MongoDB [ObjectID](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) but it's still  confusing how is that being passed in the function.

Comment: Hello, it is evident now that MongoDB is interfering with this. My main hypotheses is that, with the calls being concurrent, the mongodb call is writing on the variable, and that's how the documentID is pushed to that function. To discard this, I'd suggest trying to do the calls on the Promise.all() with *different* variables as parameter. Let me know if this helps

Comment: @DanielGomez that worked perfectly! I never thought that the original object is being modified by Mongo driver. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Fix

You should be able to fix this problem by passing a copy of `newUserObject` into MongoDB, like this:

```
await Promise.all([
    admin.firestore().collection("users").doc("FirebaseUID").set(newUserObject),
    mongoDb.collection("users").insertOne({ ...newUserObject })
])
```

Note this: `insertOne({ ...newUserObject })`.

## Explanation

When you try to insert a document into MongoDB without an `_id` field, MongoDB creates one automatically by generating an `ObjectId`. The operation basically looks like this: `newUserObject._id = new ObjectId()`.

It seems that when you run `firestore.set()` and `mongo.insertOne()` in parallel, this happens **before** the serializer step in Firestore.

So whenever the serializer starts encoding, it sees this new `_id` field and tries to encode it, and that's where it fails. Note that it sees the `_id` field because you are passing the same object reference (`newUserObject`) to both `firestore.set()` and `mongo.insertOne()`.

This explains why executing the operations sequentially works. Here you first insert the document into Firestore and only then into MongoDB, so the `_id` field is no longer a problem:

```
await admin.firestore().collection("users").doc("FirebaseUID").set(newUserObject)
await mongoDb.collection("users").insertOne(newUserObject)
```

However, if you were to reverse the order here and inserted into MongoDB first, you'd encounter the same problem.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for explanation. The spread operator did the trick :D

Comment: Didn't know that Mongo manipulates the object, even then, I would assume it to be a clone of the object rather than the source with the way javascript normally handles object.

Comment: In the strongly-typed world, e.g. Java, you'd construct a dedicated request object and pass that to the library/client. This pattern makes it clear that the request object has one purpose and one purpose only. You simply could not pass the same request object to both MongoDB and Firestore. I guess this is what the MongoDB JS client expects as well. Unfortunately, the dynamic nature of a weakly-typed language, such as JavaScript, allows the developer to do whatever, which is very flexible, but is also dangerous at times. In other words, this situation is not entirely unexpected.